# Mocking a class using Mockery with Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mockery

I'm struggling to get Mockery working with a particular Laravel 5 project. Here's the test I've written:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use App\Group;
use App\Dealer;
use App\News;
use App\User;

class PushControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase
{
    public function testCreatingPush()
    {   
        // Set user
        $this->be($this->user);

        // Mock Pushwoosh
        $this->mock = \Mockery::mock('PushWoosh\PushWoosh', array('createMessage' => true));
        $this->app->instance('PushWoosh\PushWoosh', $this->mock);
        $this->mock->shouldReceive('createMessage')->once()->andReturn(true);

        // Put together the data
        $data = array(
            'msg' => 'My first push notification'
        );

        // Send a POST request
        $response = $this->call(
            'POST',
            '/admin/api/v1/pushes',
            $data,
            array(),
            array(),
            array()
        );
        $this->assertResponseStatus(200);
    }   
}
```

And here's the controller in question:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use App\Dealer;

use Config;

class PushController extends CustomBaseController
{
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Get group for user
        $group = $this->user->group;

        // Send a Push notification
        $pushwoosh = new \PushWoosh\PushWoosh(
            // @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
            Config::get('app.pushwoosh_application'),
            '',
            '',
            Config::get('app.pushwoosh_apitoken')
            // @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
        );

        // Validate content
        $valid = $this->validate($request, [
            'msg' => 'required'
        ]);

        // Get message and target (if any)
        $msg = $request->input('msg');
        $target = $request->input('target');

        // Send push notification
        if ($target) {
            $users = User::where('dealer_id', $target)->get();
        } else {
            $users = User::where('group_id', $group->id)->get();
        }
        $pushesToSend = array();
        foreach($users as $user) {
            // Send push notifications for this user
            $push = array();
            $push['content'] = $msg;

            // Define conditions
            $push['conditions'] = ['UserID', 'EQ', $user->id];

            // Add it to the list
            array_push($pushesToSend, $push);
        }

        // Send pushes
        $response = $pushwoosh->createMessage($pushesToSend);

        // Respond
        if ($response) {
            return response()->json(200);
        } else {
            return response()->json(400);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I'm using Pushwoosh to send push messages from an admin dashboard. The library I'm using to interface with Pushwoosh is [here](https://github.com/Astutech/PushWooshPHPLibrary). I'm new to Mockery and I can't see to get it to mock the library in question - the push request still goes when I run the tests and the test fails as it didn't see the expected call. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller code, you need to be getting an instance of `PushWoosh\PushWoosh` from the Laravel container, rather than instantiating your own instance.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: Figured this out in the end - had to create a service provider for the Pushwoosh library, and inject that into the controller. After that everything worked as expected.